# Problema em execução de tarefas com dois botões no mesmo form em c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Sou novo no c#, então perdoe algum erro de novato.
Preciso colocar dois botões em um mesmo formulário,um para chamar um formulário, e outro para executar uma função
Estou tentando assim:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dados_bd dados_formulario = new dados_bd();
        conection_database conexao = new conection_database();

        dados_formulario.NOME = textBox1.Text;
        dados_formulario.LOCAL_ARMAZENAMENTO = textBox2.Text;
        dados_formulario.DESCRICAO = textBox3.Text;

        conexao.cadastro(dados_formulario);

        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
   }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 teste = new Form2();
        teste.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Se eu coloco a função de chamar outro form no button1, funciona, mas quando seto a mesma para o button 2, não. Inclusive, nenhuma função fica disponível ao button2. Gostaria de alguns esclarecimentos sobre isso.

---

Mudei o código, como sugerido mais acima, mas não funcionou. Então coloquei a sugestão na função do `button1`, que era o único que funcionava, e a função que antes estava atribuída a ele, no botão que não respondia.

Mas, eis que agora os dois botões estão chamando a `form2`, mesmo a função estando atribuída apenas ao `button1`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new Form2().Show();

       }

        public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dados_bd dados_formulario = new dados_bd();
            conection_database conexao = new conection_database();

            dados_formulario.NOME = textBox1.Text;
            dados_formulario.LOCAL_ARMAZENAMENTO = textBox2.Text;
            dados_formulario.DESCRICAO = textBox3.Text;

            conexao.cadastro(dados_formulario);

            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox3.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: E voce tem certeza que o evento está atribuído ao elemento?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, me diga como, repito, sou novato.

Comment: De dois clique no botão2 e verifica se ele está indo para o método button2_Click ou se ele está gerando um novo método.

Comment: Quando clico duas vezes, ele cai no método de button1. Preciso apenas fazer essa referência ao médoto Button2_click? Como faço?

Comment: conseguiu resolver seu problema Igor ? por favor, marque a resposta. Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente não há qualquer coisa peculiar que faça o código funcionar no primeiro botão e não funcione no segundo. De qualquer forma, eu alteraria um pouco a invocação:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Form2().Show();
}
```

`ShowDialog()` não é uma boa porque o *form* vai ser invocado como modal, o que não permite mexer em outros *forms* enquanto ele estiver aberto.

---

Possivelmente os dois botões estão apontando para o mesmo evento, no caso:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form2().Show();
    }
```

Clique em cada botão e verifique as propriedades, sobretudo na parte de eventos:

[image: Button Click]

Comment: eu não costumo programar para Windows Forms, então desculpe a ignorância. Mas porque existe esse costume de abrir os forms sem manter uma variável como uma referência para ele?

Comment: @ArturoTemplário Se você não vai precisar usar uma variável, é melhor não criar =D

Comment: Mas por exemplo, caso você tenha a possibilidade de abrir um form repetidas vezes, para, por exemplo, enviar uma mensagem. Aí você abre e fecha ele repetidas vezes. Mesmo assim é melhor não criar a variável?

Comment: @ArturoTemplário Não é o caso, certo? Se podemos fazer simples, por que devemos complicar? Deixemos os usos complicados para os casos complicados.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas explicações, sempre é bom ouvir de alguém mais experiente :)

Answer (score 2):

Seu problema está na atribuição do evento, 
você pode atribui-lo via código:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Click += button1_Click;
        button2.Click += button2_Click;
    }

    void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Evento click do botão 2
    }

    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Evento click do Botão 1
    }
```

ou pela IDE como o Cigano mostrou acima, ficaria assim:
[image: Evento do botão1]

[image: Evento do botão2]

lembrando que, ao dar 2 Cliques no botão (dentro do visual studio), ele já será levado ao evento Click, ou dê 2 cliques no espaço em branco na frente do Evento desejado, na janela de propriedades, que será gerado um novo evento para o controle.